# jhipster doesn't generate liquibase changelog for generated entities

Tags: liquibase, jhipster

I did the following:

- Created new jhipster application following the [development guide](http://jhipster.github.io/creating_an_app.html)
- Launched the Application class with hot-reload VM options as per [here](http://jhipster.github.io/development.html) from IntelliJ; command line `C:\dev\jdk1.8.0\bin\java -javaagent:spring_loaded/springloaded-jhipster.jar -noverify -Dspringloaded=plugins=io.github.jhipster.loaded.instrument.JHipsterLoadtimeInstrumentationPlugin -Didea.launcher.port=7538 "-Didea.launcher.bin.path=C:\dev\IntelliJ IDEA\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "*snip very long classpath" com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain com.mysoftware.Application`
- Created new entity using `yo jhipster:entity project` as per [here](http://jhipster.github.io/creating_an_entity.html)
- Expected results - everything works
- Obtained results - going to `http://localhost:8080/#/project` gets `org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Table "T_PROJECT" not found`
- `/src/main/resources/config/liquibase/changelog` has only `db-changelog-001.xml`
- Restart didn't help

So it seems like the step

```
 If you have used hot reload in the previous step, JHipster has automatically created a new file named src/main/resources/config/liquibase/changelog/db-changelog--002.xml.
```

from [here](http://jhipster.github.io/creating_an_entity.html) hasn't really taken place.

What am I doing wrong?

What's the easiest way to manually invoke the generation of the db-changelog-002.xml; as I'm not keen in writing it manually, the entity class already has all the information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be jhipster bug:

https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/310

Comment: Yes, I'm going to have a look at this bug (I'm the JHipster lead dev)